# Question about BPP complexity class

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, probabilistic-computation, probabilistic-complexity

Good morning everyone, I just started studying the BPP complexity class and the amplification lemma. There is one exercise about BPP that I don't understand, I hope that you can help me.

Let $L$ be a language over a finite alphabet and $M$ a $PPT$ (Probabilistic Turing Machine) such that:

- $w \in L \rightarrow P(M\ accepts\ w) \ge b$
- $w \notin L \rightarrow P(M\ accepts\ w) \le a$

where $0<a<b<1$.

I have to prove that the language $L$ is in $BPP$. This should be a fairly easy exercise, but I've tried several approaches and no one was successful. To "match" the definition of a language in $BPP$, I should have $b$ greater than $\frac{1}{2}$ and $a$ less than $\frac{1}{2}$, but the text of the exercise does not say so, we only know that $0<a<b<1$.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feels like a typical university exam and here is not the best place to answer this. EDIT: Here is a detailed answer.

Let us consider $M_n$ that given $w$, runs $n$ times $M$ and returns $1$ when
the number of accepting runs is over $n\times (b+a)/2$.

Let us consider $w\in L$. Because $P(M \text{ accepts } w)\geq b > (b+a)/2$ we know from the central limit theorem that the probability $P(M_n \text{ accepts } w)$ tends towards 1 and therefore there exists $n_b$ such that for all $n\geq n_b$, $P(M_n \text{ accepts } w)>2/3$.

In the same manner, for $w\not\in L$, we can find $n_a$ such that for all $n\geq n_a$, $P(M_n \text{ accepts } w)<1/3$. Now we see that $L$ is in $BPP$ by considering the program $M_{max(n_a,n_b)}$.

Comment: Thanks for your input, it was very appreciated. I am sorry if this was was not the proper place to ask such a "standard" question. Anyway I think I understand why the probability of getting a wrong answer becomes less than 1/2, but not why the probability of getting a right answer should become greater than 1/2 (in particular if we consider the case in which both a and b are less than 1/2).

Comment: Compute the probability of having more than $n×(a+b)/2$ accepting runs after $n$ runs of $M$ on $w$ depending on whether $w$ should be accepted or not (not an exact computation but the limit when $n\rightarrow \infty$ depending on whether $w$ is accepted or not).

Comment: Thank you, but I am actually kind of lost. Suppose we have $[(a+b)/2]>1/2$. If $w \in L$  we have $p>[(a+b)/2]>1/2$, and everything is fine according to the definition of $BPP$. But if $w \notin L$ we have $p<[(a+b)/2]$ and $[(a+b)/2]>1/2$, how can this language be in $BPP$? I don't see how we can use the amplification lemma if $p$ is greater than $1/2$. Maybe it helps if I link the source from which I am trying to self-study these concepts and where I found this exercise: https://axon.cs.byu.edu/Dan/252/misc/252-ProbTMs.pdf. It is the exercise 3.2, there is also a small suggestion.

Comment: This is indeed an example of amplification. I have edited my answer to make it more detailed.

Comment: The central limit theorem was the missing piece for me. It made sense in my head that the probability would tend towards 1 after a big number of tests, but I was not able to formally explain why. Thank you for helping me, these arguments are not very easy to self-study.